# What to do if a B+ tree key has too few outgoing pointers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, b-tree

[image: Given problem]

I try to do this problem but stuck on the step where the key 100 has 2 outgoing pointers. With what I learn in class, for it to valid for this given problem, at least 3 outgoing pointer and 1 leaf node. I'm stuck please help me.

There is an image on the top of the post, the problem is in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root node is allowed to violate the B-tree condition. Otherwise you could never have a B-tree with < N/2 elements.